# Grab digit after one of three words

Tags: python, regex

I would like to grab the digit that is shown after one of three words, as in the following examples:

```
x1 = Break, Staffel 1, Part 2 # 1
x2 = Seinfeld, Season 11 # 11
x3 = Friends, Saison 4 # 4
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
re.split(', ((Staffel)|(Season)|(Saison)) ', x)[-1]
```

Though it only works if the digit is at the end of the string. What would be abetter way to do this?

Comment: you want only digit, and you don't care of whom they belong??

Comment: Correct, so long as it comes after one of those three words.

Comment: @David542: indeed but this approach doesn't work with a serie like the 4400. An idea is to use the first comma (if it is always present)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.search()`, not `re.split()`. Then you can use a capture group to get the digits after the word.

```
m = re.search(r', (?:Staffel|Season|Saison) (\d+)', x);
if (m):
    digits = m.group(1)
```

I used `?:` in the first group, because you don't need to capture the words, the grouping is just for the alternation.

`\d` matches a digit, and `+` matches at least 1 of the preceding RE, so that matches any length number.

Comment: Perhaps of note: `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, and `\d+` is a digit that is at least one character long.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `re.findall`

```
>>> re.findall("(?:Staffel|Season|Saison)\s(\d+)",x1)
['1']
```

if you want to capture words too:

```
>>> re.findall("(Staffel|Season|Saison)\s(\d+)",x1)
[('Staffel', '1')]
```